# how to add UI elements programmatically in canvas in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas

I have a canvas inside grid. I want to add the controls dynamically(text-block and image). I am using the following code but it is not showing up anything.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="BaseGrid"
              Background="White"
              Grid.Row="2">
    <Canvas x:Name="RootCanvas"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Canvas.ZIndex="0">
        <Canvas x:Name="BaseCanvas"
                CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Canvas.Left="0"
                Canvas.Top="0"
                Canvas.ZIndex="0">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="BaseCanvasClip"/>
            </Canvas.Clip>
            <Canvas x:Name="DrawingCanvas"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Canvas.Left="0"
                    Canvas.Top="0"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="10">
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="TransparentCanvas"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Canvas.Left="0"
                    Canvas.Top="0"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="100"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
TextBlock txtBlk = new TextBlock();
txtBlk.FontSize = 14;
txtBlk.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
txtBlk.Text = CreateConceptTextBox.Text;
Canvas.SetTop(txtBlk, 100);
Canvas.SetLeft(txtBlk, 450);
//Grid.SetRow(txtBlk, 100);
//Grid.SetColumn(txtBlk, 450);
linkDiscovery.DrawingCanvas.Children.Add(txtBlk);
```

I am concern with "DrawingCanvas". What is that I am missing here?

Comment: It looks correct.  Have you tried using a literal string like `txtBlk.Text = "hello"` to test?

Comment: Ya I also tried with hard coded string but canvas was blank.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Visibility of your RootCanvas set to Collapsed, which effectively hides it and all of its children, including the DrawingCanvas.

Comment: I made it visible but than also the same result.

Comment: Your Canvas.Clip isn't defined correctly.  Since you aren't giving a size to the clip, you're actually clipping everything.  Either remove the clip or give it an actual size.